# Introduce Multiple Background Colors In Matlab GUI slider

Tags: matlab, colors, slider

I am trying to color just some parts of the slider of my matlab GUI in order to locate where some events in time occur in there. I know that the command in order to change the COMPLETE background color of the slider is:

```
set(handles.slider,'backgroundcolor','red');
```

Does anyone know how to change just some part of the background color.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can't. You would probably be better off using an image or something to indicate these events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, it seems that it cannot be done in the way I wanted to do. Finally I created the detection with a plot of a timeline axis like the next one:
[it can be seen in the right down part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82bpZ.png)

```
handles.ax=axes('NextPlot','add',...           %get the axes where the detections will be plotted for an easy finding of the interference
         'DataAspectRatio',[1 1 1],...  %#   match the scaling of each axis,
         'XLim',[0 (handles.dataLength-20000)*(1/handles.fs)*(1e3)],...               %#   set the x axis limit,
         'YLim',[0 eps],...             %#   set the y axis limit (tiny!),
         'Color','none',...
         'Position',[0.02 0.35 0.96 1]);  
     set(handles.ax,'Parent',handles.detectAx);axes(handles.ax); %get the axes where the plot will be made
```

Finally, you just havet to plot the values in the line you want

Comment: Accept your own answer ;).